# How do I execute a subselect (or large group by) of SQL in Rails 4 with ActiveModel?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to execute this type of SQL and get an array of Model1:

```
select model1.*,
  (select sum(prop) from model2 where model2.model1_id = model1.id) as total
  from model1
  where model1.parent_id is null
  order by total desc
```

I tried to use

> @parent.model1.select("model2.prop").where(parent_id: nil).group(:id).order(:prop => :desc)

but it gave an error about ' missing FROM-clause entry for table'. I don't know how to use sub-selects in Rails, and it's not in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). The only thing I can think to do is loop through each model1 and find the sum of the property I'm looking for, but that would generate N+1 queries and be really slow compared to 1 straight SQL. I suppose using a group by and grouping by every single property of model1 could also work, but that sounds messy.

Answer (score 0):

Holy cow I did it!

> @post.comments.select(Comment.columns.map{|c| c.name}).select("(select coalesce(sum(vote),0) as total from votes where votes.comment_id = comments.id) as total").order("total desc")